# Now that LoL / Valorant is added to Gamepass, how can I redeem their benefit without installing it from Microsoft store?

Tags: league-of-legends, valorant, xbox-game-pass, microsoft-store

Title. If the user is Game pass user, user can receive every champions and agents ([Source](https://news.xbox.com/en-us/2022/12/08/riot-games-and-xbox-game-pass-benefits-coming-soon/)).

Now, it seems to be [requiring me to install LoL / Valorant via Microsoft Store](https://news.xbox.com/en-us/2022/12/12/riot-games-and-benefits-come-to-game-pass/).

> How to Access Your Benefits:
>
> ・Install the Xbox App on your PC and ensure its updated to the latest version
>
> ・Open the Xbox app on PC and select any of Riot’s games
>
> ・Click Play or Install

I already have them on my harddrive, so I would like to redeem it without installing them from the store. But there seems to be no way to doing so.

Is it possible to redeem its benefit without installing it from the Store? or, am I forced to install it from the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently only the Microsoft side was trying to force installing these games from their store.

From [this Riot's page](https://www.riotgames.com/en/riot-game-pass-benefits),

> How can I link my Riot Account to my Xbox profile to unlock benefits within Riot’s games?
>
> You can link your accounts by navigating to the [Xbox Game Pass Welcome Page](https://account.riotgames.com/xbox-game-pass-link). You may be asked to sign into your Riot Account and sign in with your Xbox profile to complete the linking process. Access to benefits requires Xbox Game Pass subscription, sold separately. Game catalog varies over time.

That "Xbox Game Pass Welcome Page" is a link to a page to connect Riot account and Microsoft account. From there, you login to your Microsoft account and Riot account. Once you've logged in to your account, follow the instructions. Congratulations, your accounts are now connected.